# A robust way to find out if a texture format is supported by OpenGL implementation

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am trying to find out what texture formats are *actually* supported by the OpenGL implementation. I know there is a function glGetInternalformat(), but it is only helpful in GL4.3+ and is almost useless in GLES3.1 and before. So instead I am trying to create a small texture, allocate storage for it using glTexStorage2D() and check the error code. However it seems like on OpenGL ES3.1 the function succeeds for all formats I test, but later when I try to upload the actual data to the texture, glTexSubImage2D() fails. This happens for at least all 16-bit normalized integer formats (which are indeed not listed as required in ES3.1 spec).
So is there a better and more robust way to query the texture format support?

Comment: Your best bet would be knowing which extensions provide which formats and querying that instead. For instance, `GL_RGB16_SNORM` is provided by `GL_EXT_texture_norm16` in OpenGL ES 3.1+. I wrote a piece of software a while back that lets you track OpenGL constants back to their extension by parsing the OpenGL registry XML file, you may find it useful - the source code is [here](https://github.com/andon13/glvs/).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thank you! I was hoping there exists some general way to find an answer to this question. Tracking which formats are required by every particular OpenGL version and which formats are enabled by extensions may require some noticeable typing.